# Как вывести подрубрики из указанной рубрики в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Не могу найти в инете эту инфу, буду благодарен за объяснение или пример вывода... Знаю что за это отвечает функция get_the_category , но она вроде как выводит только текущие рубрики.

Answer (score 1):

Используй параметр child_of

```
$term_id = 111; // id родительской категории
get_the_category( array( 'child_of' => $term_id ) );
```

Только оно не вернет тебе пустые категории. Для этого параметр hide_empty надо задать, как false.

Answer (score 0):

Мой криворукий пример вывода. Категории внутри них категории, внутри них - снова категории и тд)

```
<?
    $parent = get_query_var('cat');
    $arg = array(
        'parent' => $parent,
        'hide_empty' => 0
    );
    $all_cat = get_categories($arg);
    if($all_cat){
        foreach ($all_cat as $cat){
            $mid = $cat->term_id;
            $slug = $cat->slug;
            $cat_img = get_option("category_$mid");
            if($slug == "tria"){?>
                <div class="c-item -item -tria">
                    <? the_custom_logo();
            }else{
                if($slug == 'fixator'||$slug == 'glue'||$slug == 'germetic'||$slug == 'indgrease'){
                    $n = 0;
                }elseif ($slug == 'recovery'||$slug == 'metal'||$slug == 'surface'||$slug == 'cleaner'){
                    $n = 2;
                }
                echo '<div class="c-item -item '.$slug.'" style="background-image: url('.$cat_img['cat_bg'].'); order:'.$n.';">';
                $sub_cats = get_categories( array(
                    'child_of' => $mid,
                    'hide_empty' => 0
                ) );
                if( $sub_cats ){?>
                    <h3><? echo $cat->name; ?></h3>
                    <div class="link-row">
                        <?foreach( $sub_cats as $sub_cat ){
                            echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($sub_cat->term_id).'" class="btn -grey c-link">'.$sub_cat->name.'</a>';
                        }?>
                    </div>

                <?}else{?>
                    <h3><? echo $cat->name; ?></h3>
                    <div class="link-row">
                        <?echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id).'" class="btn -grey c-link">'.$cat->name.'</a>';?>
                    </div>
                <?}
            }
            echo '</div>';

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }?>
```